# Calculate the average between the same month in a time series

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset between 2002 - 2018 which contains 1 value per month, 198 rows in total.

I want to know how I can average all the values from the same month (e.g. January/2003 + ... + January/2018)

```
dateparse = lambda dates: pd.datetime.strptime(dates, '%Y-%m-%d') 
df = pd.read_csv('turbidez.csv', parse_dates=['date'], index_col='date',date_parser=dateparse)
data = df['x']
data.head()

date          
2002-07-31    8.466111
2002-08-31    6.234259
2002-09-30    8.160763
2002-10-31    4.927685
2002-11-30    8.125012
```

Searching a bit I visit [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57914948/get-average-by-months-of-a-time-series-all-januaries-all-februaries-etc), but couldn't apply it properly to my data.

Thank you in advance for any assistance.

Comment: please provide the code to generate dataframe

Comment: Code used to generate the dataframe added :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `pandas.to_datetime` and `pandas.Series.dt.month`:

```
# Sample data
        date         x
0 2002-07-31  8.466111
1 2003-07-31  6.234259
2 2002-09-30  8.160763
3 2003-09-30  4.927685
4 2002-11-30  8.125012

df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"] )
new_df = df.groupby(df["date"].dt.month).sum()
print(new_df)
```

Output:

```
              x
date           
7     14.700370
9     13.088448
11     8.125012
```